# MS Chart - How to overlay data from 2 years on one chart

Tags: vb.net, winforms, mschart

Using VB.net in a winforms app I have created a chart of financial data for 2015 that includes 4 series relating to outstanding A/R during the year.  That all works well as shown:

[image]

Now the user wants the same data from 2014 overlayed on the same chart so that he can compare this year to the prior year.

I have tried the following:

1) Adding a second data source with the 2014 data, that doesn't appear to be a go

2) I have played around with using a single datasource of 2015 & 2014 data and filtering the datasource for each group series w/o luck.

Here is my code:

```
     chtAR.DataSource = Nothing
    chtAR.Series.Clear()
    chtAR.DataSource = DS2.Tables(CurrentYear)
    chtAR.ChartAreas(0).AxisX.Interval = 2
    chtAR.ChartAreas(0).AxisY.Interval = 250000
    chtAR.ChartAreas(0).AxisX.Maximum = 52

    '*** Current Year ***

    chtAR.Series.Add("AvgAR$")
    chtAR.Series("AvgAR$").LegendText = CurrentYear + " Avg A/R $"
    chtAR.Series("AvgAR$").ChartType = DataVisualization.Charting.SeriesChartType.Line
    chtAR.Series("AvgAR$").BorderWidth = 3
    chtAR.Series("AvgAR$").Color = Color.Green
    chtAR.Series("AvgAR$").XValueMember = DS2.Tables(CurrentYear).Columns("WeekNo").ToString
    chtAR.Series("AvgAR$").YValueMembers = DS2.Tables(CurrentYear).Columns("AVG A/R").ToString

    chtAR.Series.Add("AvgAR$PastDue")
    chtAR.Series("AvgAR$PastDue").LegendText = CurrentYear + " Avg A/R Past Due $"
    chtAR.Series("AvgAR$PastDue").ChartType = DataVisualization.Charting.SeriesChartType.Line
    chtAR.Series("AvgAR$PastDue").BorderWidth = 3
    chtAR.Series("AvgAR$PastDue").Color = Color.DarkBlue
    chtAR.Series("AvgAR$PastDue").XValueMember = DS2.Tables(CurrentYear).Columns("WeekNo").ToString
    chtAR.Series("AvgAR$PastDue").YValueMembers = DS2.Tables(CurrentYear).Columns("AVG Past Due A/R").ToString

    chtAR.Series.Add("TotalAR$")
    chtAR.Series("TotalAR$").LegendText = CurrentYear + " total A/R $"
    chtAR.Series("TotalAR$").ChartType = DataVisualization.Charting.SeriesChartType.Line
    chtAR.Series("TotalAR$").BorderWidth = 3
    chtAR.Series("TotalAR$").Color = Color.LightGreen
    chtAR.Series("TotalAR$").XValueMember = DS2.Tables(CurrentYear).Columns("WeekNo").ToString
    chtAR.Series("TotalAR$").YValueMembers = DS2.Tables(CurrentYear).Columns("CurrentAR").ToString

    chtAR.Series.Add("PastDueAR$")
    chtAR.Series("PastDueAR$").LegendText = CurrentYear + " Past Due A/R $"
    chtAR.Series("PastDueAR$").ChartType = DataVisualization.Charting.SeriesChartType.Line
    chtAR.Series("PastDueAR$").BorderWidth = 3
    chtAR.Series("PastDueAR$").Color = Color.LightBlue
    chtAR.Series("PastDueAR$").XValueMember = DS2.Tables(CurrentYear).Columns("WeekNo").ToString
    chtAR.Series("PastDueAR$").YValueMembers = DS2.Tables(CurrentYear).Columns("PastDueAR").ToString
```

Does anyone have some suggestions on how I should handle this ?

Would something like Telerik be a good option ?

Thanks !!

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone is interested, I figured this out.

My solution was to change the data layout returned from my query.

The database table looked like this:

Date | WeekNo | CurrentA/R | PastDueAR | etc....|

I wrote an ugly query (with several sub queries) that returned a table like this:

WeekNo | PastYearCurrentA/R | CurrentYearA/R | PastYearPastDueA/R | CurrentYearPastDueA/R| etc.......

That allowed me to have a single datasource that contained all the series info I needed.

New version looks like this:

[image]